# Weird behaviour with std::getline and std::vector<std::string>

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
std::vector<std::string> final_output;
std::string input;

int tries = 0;
std::cin >> tries;

int counter = 0;
while(counter < tries) {

    std::getline(std::cin, input); 
    final_output.push_back(input);
    ++counter;

}
```

Given the input:

```
3
Here Goes
Here Goes 2
```

The output is:

```
<blank line>
Here Goes
Here Goes 2
```

Weirdly, it seems to enter a blank line as input for the first time it runs.

However, if I have the code as:

```
int tries = 3;         // explicitly specifying the number of tries
int counter = 0;
while(counter < tries) {}
```

It works as expected. Why is the `std::cin >> tries` causing the code to fail?

I have tested it with VC++ 2010 and g++ 4.4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter the number for `tries`, you hit the return key. After you read `tries`, the carriage return from hitting the return key is still sitting in the input buffer. That carriage return will normally be translated to a new-line character. Your next call to `getline` reads everything in the input buffer up to the next new-line. Since the first character is a new-line, it reads that as a line of zero length (i.e., zero characters before the new-line).

Answer (score 1):

The newline of the first entry is still in the input buffer.

You can call `std::cin.ignore();` just after reading tries from `cin`.

This way the newline gets discarded.

I found a good link that explains plenty of things regarding the use of I/O:

- http://www.augustcouncil.com/~tgibson/tutorial/iotips.html

Comment: But I don't understand? I just inputted an `int`. Why would there be a new line after that?

Comment: Aah I see. It is in the buffer. Thanks.

Comment: yes, the newline is what tells cin the input has been done but it comes also in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You have nothing to absorb the `'\n'` from the first line in your standalone `std::cin >> tries`.